# Mongodb - to group documents and get document from each group with max value of a field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo collection where the documents are never updated, rather the most current document is read, and a new document is inserted with some fields updated on it. These common documents share an identifier `document_identifier` that distinguishes them from others.

I want to perform a query that performs the following:
Get all documents whose `customer_id` is X, group them by their `document_identifier`, and from each group take the document with the max `updated_at` timestamp. It should return the documents in their entirety (all of their properties).

Example data set:

```
{
    document_identifier: "abc",
    updated_at: 1000,
    customer_id: "123",
    ...  
},

{
    document_identifier: "def",
    updated_at: 1001,
    customer_id: "123",
    ...
},

{
    document_identifier: "abc",
    updated_at: 1002,
    customer_id: "123",
    ...
},

{
    document_identifier: "def",
    updated_at: 10003,
    customer_id: "123",
    ...
},

{
    document_identifier: "xyz",
    updated_at: 1004,
    customer_id: "999",
    ...
},

{
    document_identifier: "abc",
    updated_at: 1005,
    customer_id: "123",
    ...
},

{
    document_identifier: "def",
    updated_at: 1006,
    customer_id: "123",
    ...
},
```

In the above example if I wanted to query on `customer_id` of "123" the result would be:

```
{
    document_identifier: "abc",
    updated_at: 1005,
    customer_id: "123",
    ...
},

{
    document_identifier: "def",
    updated_at: 1006,
    customer_id: "123",
    ...
},
```

I've been steered towards the Mongo aggregate framework but can't seem to get it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is what I have right now and it appears to be working, but I'm not sure that it's the most optimal:

```
db.my_colleciton.aggregate([
    {
       $match: {customer_id: <value to query on>}
    },

    {
        $sort: {updated_at: -1}
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$document_identifier",
            my_doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },

    {
        "$replaceRoot": {newRoot: "$my_doc"}
    }
])
```

Comment: I think your results is inaccurate for customer 123 document id "def", I think this should show updated_at value of 10003 instead of 1006 since 10003 is larger than 1006.

Comment: @barrypicker I've made a couple edits. I was missing some info and I fixed a typo.

Comment: Even so, your expected results are as I would expect.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding your intentions?

Comment: Careful on assuming the $sort before $group will provide the expected result.  MongoDB documentation is clear that $group does not order its output documents, thus $first is now suspect.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: Actually, looking at the documentation again, Mongo states for $first "Returns a value from the first document for each group. Order is only defined if the documents are in a defined order."  I think they are referring to the $sort before $group.  If so, your query is safe.  I wish the documentation was more clear.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly I think this query might help...

```
db.records.aggregate(
[
    { $group: {
        _id: {customer_id: "$customer_id", document_identifier: "$document_identifier"},
        max_updated_at: { $max:  "$updated_at" }
    }}
])
```

the idea is to group on two fields, `customer_id` and `document_identifier`.  For that combo show the max `updated_at` which is expected to be a rolling integer.

For the dataset you provided my results show...

```
{ "_id" : { "customer_id" : "123", "document_identifier" : "def" }, "max_updated_at" : 10003 }
{ "_id" : { "customer_id" : "999", "document_identifier" : "xyz" }, "max_updated_at" : 1004 }
{ "_id" : { "customer_id" : "123", "document_identifier" : "abc" }, "max_updated_at" : 1005 }
```

The format of the output differs from your example.  Is that OK, or do you require the format of the output to match your examples?

**Edit:**
So the OP requests the format of the output match the expected format described in the question.  Without further ado...

```
db.records.aggregate(
[
    { $group: {
        _id: {customer_id: "$customer_id", document_identifier: "$document_identifier"},
        max_updated_at: { $max:  "$updated_at" }
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        document_identifier: "$_id.document_identifier",
        updated_at: "$max_updated_at",
        customer_id: "$_id.customer_id"

    }}
]
)
```

Now the output looks like:

```
{ "document_identifier" : "def", "updated_at" : 10003, "customer_id" : "123" }
{ "document_identifier" : "xyz", "updated_at" : 1004, "customer_id" : "999" }
{ "document_identifier" : "abc", "updated_at" : 1005, "customer_id" : "123" }
```

**Edit number 2:**

OK, so the OP has many more fields than represented in the question, and would like to see all the fields for matching documents.  Here is the query so far...

```
db.records.aggregate(
[
    { $match: { customer_id: "123" }},
    { $group: {
        _id: {customer_id: "$customer_id", document_identifier: "$document_identifier"},
        max_updated_at: { $max:  "$updated_at" }
    }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: "records",
        let: {
          customer_id: "$_id.customer_id",
          document_identifier: "$_id.document_identifier",
          max_updated_at: "$max_updated_at"
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: [ "$customer_id", "$$customer_id"] },
                  { $eq: [ "$document_identifier", "$$document_identifier"] },
                  { $eq: [ "$updated_at", "$$max_updated_at"] }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "result"
    }},
    { $unwind: "$result" } ,
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$result" } }
]
)
```

This now matches on customer id first.  It then does a self join using $lookup, then $replaceRoot to show the original documents only.  This preserves the original document format regardless of how many fields are present.

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5db07a5d3cf0c979dd020f85"), "document_identifier" : "def", "updated_at" : 10003, "customer_id" : "123" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5db07a5d3cf0c979dd020f87"), "document_identifier" : "abc", "updated_at" : 1005, "customer_id" : "123" }
```

Comment: I want the entire document in each case though, I don't just want some fields. Also I just tried the query and it doesn't quite match up with the expected behavior.

Comment: @lorenzo - output has been reformatted..  Please review.

Comment: in reality the documents have about 30 properties and it doesn't seem practical to have to call out that I want every single property.

Comment: Well, my examples are based on what information I have been provided.  If you need the entire document, you could use the $group to identify records then perform a self join using $lookup.  I will mock up something and edit my answer...

Comment: I think there needs to be a $match pipeline to match on the `customer_id` that we are querying on

Comment: @lorenzo - please review the last part of my answer - I have added $lookup and $replaceRoot to dynamically provide the entire document regardless of how many fields are present.

Comment: seems a bit complicated. I edited my post to include a sample that I believe to be working, but not having worked with Mongo in a while I'm not 100% sure that this is the optimal solution.

Comment: @lorenzo - I think you are inserting and not updating because you want performance and history.  Your use-case is not clear so I can only draw assumptions.  To be optimal I would need to understand more details about your use.  There are other strategies for performance, such as sharding.  Also document schema design considerations impact performance as does indexing and hard drive subsystems and IO benchmarks.  One approach is to alter historical records on insert, mark the inserted record as most recent and index.  This greatly simplifies the find query at the cost of insert complications.

Answer (score 0):

First sort **descending** by `updated_at` then [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by `document_identifier` and pick the first document for that particular group via [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)

And retain fields by the same idea of **`$first`**.

**Query:** [Demo Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JkqSXr8TfBs)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { updated_at: -1 } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$document_identifier",
        document_identifier: { $first: "$document_identifier" },
        updated_at: { $first: "$updated_at" },
        customer_id: { $first: "$customer_id" }
      }
    }
  ]).pretty();
```

**Results:**

```
{
    "_id" : "abc",
    "document_identifier" : "abc",
    "updated_at" : 1005,
    "customer_id" : "123"
},
{
    "_id" : "xyz",
    "document_identifier" : "xyz",
    "updated_at" : 1004,
    "customer_id" : "999"
},
{
    "_id" : "def",
    "document_identifier" : "def",
    "updated_at" : 10003,
    "customer_id" : "123"
}
```

Comment: The OP has more fields than what is represented in the question, and would like to preserve these fields on output.

Comment: I don't see anything off with getting all the fields like this (30 or more) or the way you showed with projection previously. Though `$replaceRoot` would do the job but I find it intensive if the pipeline doesn't have good amount of transformation and replace to.

Comment: I agree with your statement.  The less work the server must do the faster the output.  One challenge is to provide output for dynamic or changing document structures.  If the structures are different or have the potential of changing in the future the projection stage must deal with that.  I am not sure if this is a concern for the OP or not.

Comment: Well that is a really very good point that I did not think of before replying at previous comment. +1.