# Is there a way to only get always the newest version of a document in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In a MongoDB we have the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
    "myId": "aaa",
    "name":  "my name"
    "version": 1
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("124"),
    "myId": "aaa",
    "name":  "my namE"
    "version": 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("125"),
    "myId": "bbb",
    "name":  "my name"
    "version": 1
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("223"),
    "myId": "bbb",
    "name":  "my name"
    "version": 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("334"),
    "myId": "bbb",
    "name":  "my namse"
    "version": 3
}
```

myId is my own identifier, this is used to identify a document and to get all versions.
Is there anyway to get all data, but ***only*** the newest version?
I want this as my result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("124"),
    "myId": "aaa",
    "name":  "my namE"
    "version": 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("334"),
    "myId": "bbb",
    "name":  "my namse"
    "version": 3
}
```

Of course i can sort it by the version, but I will still get all documents
`db.getCollection('profiles').find({}).sort({"version": -1})`

I searched a lot but I haven't found a way to do it.

Thanks for your input

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67684323/8987128), in your case you can sort by `version` in descending order, group by `myId`.

Comment: Thanks @turivishal, looks promising, I will try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the Aggregate Framework.  Assuming the name of your collection is `test` her is a performant query option...

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $sort: { version: -1 } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$myId",
        original_id: { $first: "$_id" },
        name: { $first: "$name" },
        version: { $first: "$version" }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: "$original_id",
        myId: "$_id",
        name: "$name",
        version: "$version"
      }
    }
  ]).pretty();
```

The strategy is fairly straight forward, we perform 3 operations....

1. sort
2. group
3. project

the first stage - sort - merely presents the data in correct sorted order descending on the field `version`.  Next we group by the psuedo key field `myId` and catch the first occurrence in the pipeline since by this stage they are sorted.  Since the MongoDB $group aggregation stage operator requires the group by key field to be called `_id` we must catch the field `myId` in the `_id` field.  We must also catch the original `_id` field, so we catch it in a field called `original_id`.  Next we correct the field names using a $project pipeline stage.  here we take what was in the field `original_version` and rename it `_id`, and we take what was in `_id` and rename it back to the original psuedo key field `myId`.  The other two fields are merely included along for the ride, and are mapped to their own original names respectively..  Tack on the .pretty() to format the output to make it nice to read.

A similar question was asked about a year and a half ago on SO thread [Mongodb - to group documents and get document from each group with max value of a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526401/mongodb-to-group-documents-and-get-document-from-each-group-with-max-value-of/58527132#58527132).  I argued a different approach at the time, but I always admired the reporters strategy and solution.  It is simple and elegant.

... And by the way, ObjectID("123") is not valid for an ObjectID.  For this reason I tested with strings instead of ObjectIds...  Here is my insert statement to test with...

```
db.test.insertMany([
   {
      "_id":"123",
      "myId":"aaa",
      "name":"my name",
      "version":1
   },
   {
      "_id":"124",
      "myId":"aaa",
      "name":"my namE",
      "version":2
   },
   {
      "_id":"125",
      "myId":"bbb",
      "name":"my name",
      "version":1
   },
   {
      "_id":"223",
      "myId":"bbb",
      "name":"my name",
      "version":2
   },
   {
      "_id":"334",
      "myId":"bbb",
      "name":"my namse",
      "version":3
   }
])
```

If you add additional fields to your documents and expect them to participate in this query, you need to remember to add them to the aggregation pipeline query too otherwise they are stripped out of the output during the $group phase...

Comment: Thanks for this answer. it looks really promising!